# mysql date shows null

Tags: mysql, date

I want to take today's dob and I used

```
select retailer_id
from IPEX_LOAN_REGISTRATION_DETAILS
where
month(date_of_birth) = month(curdate()) 
AND dayofmonth(date_of_birth) = dayofmonth(curdate());
```

as everyone has suggested. However, it doesn't show any birthday and I checked that there's one user who has birthday. So, I tried to check if I can take the month only, and I used

```
select month(date_of_birth) from IPEX_LOAN_REGISTRATION_DETAILS
```

and it showed me NULL data. Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: are you setting `date_of_birth` correctly?

Comment: `MONTH()` requires date or datetime

Comment: what do u mean date_of_birth correctly? do u mean the name of the column? and month() requires date or datetime? thank you